# why does listener on button behave differently than listener on form (both to event submit)

Tags: javascript, forms, addeventlistener, event-listener

I have a form to enquire a price. The price is returned via an Ajax (is it - not sure?) request and then the submit button within the same form is displayed.

Just staying with the first enquiry button, if I use `formQuote.addEventListener('submit', (event) => {` the price is loaded and the 2nd button is displayed. If, however, I use `btnPricecheck.addEventListener('submit', (event) => {` as shown below, the page reloads, removing all entered data (note `formQuote` vs `btnPricecheck` before `addEventListener`). It is the 5th code line.

```js
const formQuote = document.querySelector('#quote');
  if (formQuote) {
     btnPricecheck = document.getElementById('btn-pricecheck');
     btnEnquiry = document.getElementById('btn-enquiry');
      btnPricecheck.addEventListener('submit', (event) => {
            event.preventDefault();
        
            fromDate = formQuote.elements["fromDate"].value;
            toDate = formQuote.elements["toDate"].value;
            apptmnt = $('input[name="apptmnt"]:checked').val();

            parameters = '';
            if (fromDate) parameters += 'fromDate=' + fromDate;
            if (toDate) parameters += '&toDate=' + toDate;
            if(apptmnt) { 
                if (parameters.length > 1) {
                    parameters += '&apptmnt=' + apptmnt
                }
                else {
                    parameters += 'apptmnt=' + apptmnt
                }
            }
    console.log( parameters);
            
            $('#priceDisplay').load('forms/quote.php?' + parameters);
            if (document.getElementById('total'))
                showPersonForm();
            window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);
      });

      btnEnquiry.addEventListener('submit', (event) => {
            // disable default action
            event.preventDefault();
            
            var cpFields = ['surname', 'firstName', 'email', 'street', 'zip', 'city', 'country', 'phone', 'notes'];
            for (var fld in cpFields) {
                document.getElementById("c_"+fld).value = document.getElementById(fld).value;
            }                       
            // configure a request
            const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open('POST', 'forms/confirmation.php');         
            // Define what happens on successful data submission
            xhr.addEventListener( 'load', function( event ) {
              alert( 'Yeah! Data sent and response loaded.' );
              console.log(xhr.responseText);
            } );            
            // Define what happens in case of error
            xhr.addEventListener(' error', function( event ) {
              alert( 'Oops! Something went wrong.' );
              console.log(xhr.responseText);
            } );
            // prepare form data
            let data = new FormData(formQuote);     
            // send request
            xhr.send(data);     
            // listen for `load` event
            xhr.onload = () => {
                console.log(xhr.responseText);
            }
      });
  }
```

UPDATE:
what I noticed, `fromDate = formQuote.elements["fromDate"].value;` can hardly work here, but `fromDate = document.getElementById["fromDate"].value;`doesn't, either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In second case event handler just does not run, so `event.preventDefault()` is neither executed so browser sends your form to URL its (I mean, `<form>`'s) `action` attribute(that might be just current page's address if you have not specified any). And it looks like "page reloads and data is cleared".

Why this happens? Because button does not trigger `submit` event, so handler you attach is never being called.

Though, you can set up event handler *upper* in the tree, than it(event) is actually happens. Say, you could put `submit` event handler on `<body>` and it would be executed due to event bubbling. But since bubbling never happens to lower elements(children), but only to higher(parents) it would not help you here.

Comment: ok, this makes sense. I saw this here somewhere as an solution, to use 2 buttons within the same form. Is there any chance to have 2 buttons for 2 steps in the same form and listening to them separately? Workaround would be to either copy the 1st form data into the 2nd (hidden) or to to send the data to either of the targeted pages based on some value evaluated in the js function

Comment: @w461that's completely different question that hard to answer in comments; in short: you either can provide buttons with `name`/`value` and then upon `submit` event is fired, you will have data for button has been clicked. Or, as an alternative, you use handler for `click` and check what exact button been clicked(but then you will need to specify `type="button"` to prevent browser from sending form)